# ASP.net MVC2 Accessing two tables from a partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, list, viewmodel

Im looking for some advice on the best way to access two database tables from one partial view.

I have a view model that includes two lists of objects, customers and customer sites,

```
public class CustomerSitesListViewModel
{
    public IList<CustomerSite> CustomerSites { get; set; }
    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
    public IList<Customer> customers { get; set; }
}
```

I have a partial view that inherits the view model

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<CustomerDatabase.WebUI.Models.CustomerSitesListViewModel>" %>
<ul id="list-of-sites">
<li><%: Model.AddressLine1 %></li>
<li><%: Model.AddressLine2%></li>
<li><%: Model.AddressLine3%></li>
```

Then i have a for each loop in the main view that inserts the partial view

```
<% foreach (var customerSite in Model.CustomerSites) { %>
<% %>
<% Html.RenderPartial("CustomerSiteSummary", customerSite); %>
<%} %>
```

Now in the partial view id like to be able to access properties for both objects both customer and customer site, i thought i would be able to access them like this

```
<%Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.customers.CustomerName)%>
<%Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.CustomerSite.AddressLine1)%>
```

However the furthest i can get is

```
Model.customers
```

Is there anyway to access the customer properties, i.e. customers.CustomerName,

This is one aspect of MVC that i really dont understand, ive been stuck with this for over a week now, would appreciate any advice anyone can offer.

Regards

Liam

Update=======

Ive added the following view models

Customer View Model

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryContactName { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryContactNo { get; set; }
    public SiteViewModel Site { get; set; }

}
```

Site View Model

```
public class SiteViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
}
```

Master view model

```
public class CustomerSitesListViewModel
{
    public IList<CustomerSite> CustomerSites { get; set; }
    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
    public IList<Customer> customers { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

Ive strongly typed the view to the CustomerSitesListViewModel

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"   Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<CustomerDatabase.WebUI.Models.CustomerSitesListViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<h2>Customer Sites</h2>
<%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Customers) %>
<div class="pager">
<%: Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("List", "CustomerSites", new {   page = x }))%>
```

Ive added a template into Views Shared/DisplayTemplates

CustomerSitesListViewModel.ascx

```
<%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Customers.) %>
```

This still wont let me access the properties, i can access both the customers and customersites objects but not the properties, so the furthest it will let me go is x.Customers or x.CustomerSites

This is my controller that returns the two lists of customers and sites

```
 public ViewResult List([DefaultValue(1)] int page)
    {
        var customerSitesToShow = customerSiteRepository.CustomerSites;
        var customersToShow = customerRepository.Customers;
        var viewModel = new CustomerSitesListViewModel
        {

            CustomerSites = customerSitesToShow.Skip((page - 1) *   PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList(),
            customers = customersToShow.Skip((page - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList(),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItems = customerSitesToShow.Count()
            }
        };

        return View(viewModel);  //Passed to view as ViewData.Model
```

Can you offer any advice on where i am going wrong?

Many Thanks

Liam

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not using view models. You have just defined some `CustomerSitesListViewModel` class in which you have stuffed your domain models as properties which is inappropriate for the requirements of this particular view.

So the first thing to do is to define a clean view model. You said that you need to access in your partial properties for both the customer and the customer site. So there must be some relation between them.

Let's start by defining this view model:

```
public class SiteViewModel
{
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SiteViewModel Site { get; set; }
}
```

and finally the main view model:

```
public class CustomerSitesListViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

now let's move on to the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // TODO: query repositories and map the domain objects 
    // they returned to the actual view model. Can't help much
    // here as I don't know how are your domain models and repositories
    // organized

    var viewModel = new CustomerSitesListViewModel
    {
        Customers = ...
    };
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

and then the main view which will be strongly typed to `CustomerSitesListViewModel`:

```
<%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Customers) %>
```

and finally we need to define an editor template which will be rendered automatically for eqch element of the Customers collection. It should be located in `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/CustomerSitesListViewModel.ascx`:

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<CustomerSitesListViewModel>" 
%>
<%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name) %>
<%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Site.AddressLine1) %>
```

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, hi thanks for your reply, ive followed your instructions and still it wont work, ive updated the post above would be grateful if you could give me some more advice please.

Comment: @liam, read my post carefully. The `CustomerSitesListViewModel.ascx` is strongly typed to `CustomerSitesListViewModel`. There you could access its properties. The `<%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Customers) %>` bit is inside the `Index.aspx` view.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, thanks i did strongly type it to the view model, ive got it working now but i had to add public SiteViewModel Sites { get; set; } to the CustomerSitesListViewModel and remove the Ienumerable syntax to get access to both objects

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, now im faced with how to render the template in a for each loop inside the view.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, when using the template do i just need this one single line in the view <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Customers) %>? as properties are defined in the template.

Comment: @liam, you don't write any for loop!!! You simply write `<%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Customers) %>` inside Index.aspx and this will automatically loop through all elements and render the corresponding display template : `CustomerSitesListViewModel.ascx` for each element of the Customers collection.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, thats what i thought but when i do that i get an empty model, the page renders without error but no customers or sites are displayed in the view.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov Are the display templates a new feature with MVC3 as im using 2?

Comment: @liam, no they were introduced in ASP.NET MVC 2. Here's a blog post where you can read more about them: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, thanks i can now get the syntax working to access both models from the partial view, im still not returning any data, this is because i don't have a LINQ query returning data for the Customer Collection in the controller.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - i think im nearly there, but i need another linq query in the controller to return both the sites and customers, im updating the post if you would be kind enough to help again, really appreciate your help.